# WCF Calling Error: The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly

Tags: wcf, azure-web-app-service

I have a really annoying problem regarding with **WCF Services**. I have a wcf service which has basichttpbindng.

The service is published to Azure Web App and timeout is set to 20 minutes. After **180** seconds I get the following error:

> The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed
>   unexpectedly

I have a method like following:

```
public ProcessResult TestErrorMessage()

        {
            try
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(320000);
                return new ProcessResult()
                {

                };
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw ex;
            }
        }

        [OperationContract]
        ProcessResult TestErrorMessage();
```

You can find both Config below.

**Server Config:**

```
 <bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="basicBindingConfiguration" closeTimeout="00:20:00" openTimeout="00:20:00" receiveTimeout="00:20:00" sendTimeout="00:20:00" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
      <!--<security mode="None">-->
      <security mode="Transport">
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<services>
  <service name="Tefal.WebService.Integration.DivaIntegration" behaviorConfiguration="customBehavior">
    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="basicBindingConfiguration" contract="Tefal.WebService.Integration.IDivaIntegration" />
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="customBehavior">
      <!--<serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="false" />-->
      <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
      <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

**Cleint config:**

```
 <bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IDivaIntegration" closeTimeout="00:20:00"
      openTimeout="00:20:00" receiveTimeout="00:20:00" sendTimeout="00:20:00"
      maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
      useDefaultWebProxy="true">
      <security mode="Transport" />
    </binding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IDivaIntegration1" receiveTimeout="00:20:00"
      sendTimeout="00:20:00" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647"
      maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2000000" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
        maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="ClientBehavior">
      <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

Comment: Also I have checked all logs via traceviewer, the process is going on in backend. (I have tried with real method. This method is just proof that it got an erro after 180 second.)

Comment: Please add your config as a text instead of image

Comment: What is your client config?

Comment: Hi Selim, I shared both config as answer. Thanks for your support!

Comment: Please add configs to your question not as an answer.

Comment: Done. Could you please check ?